# How do I show all posts but exclude a specific category on wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, templating

I have this code that right now spits out all the posts regardless of category.

```
<?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
<?php global $query_string;
    query_posts( $query_string . '&ignore_sticky_posts=1' ); ?>

    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>

    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); // reset the query ?>
```

How Do I do the same thing, except exclude posts with a category 'blog'?

Answer (score 2):

You can use below thing :-

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'cat=-12,-34,-56' );
```

OR

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'category__not_in' => array( 2, 6 ) ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! You had to do replace

```
query_posts( $query_string . '&ignore_sticky_posts=1' );
```

with

```
query_posts( $query_string . '&ignore_sticky_posts=1&cat=-' . get_cat_ID( 'Blogs' ) );
```

Comment: Just a tip: **NEVER** use `query_posts` for custom queries. It alters the main query and break pagination. You **should** use `WP_Query` instead